# Question regarding notation involving $\arg \min$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, notation, least-squares

The operator $\min$ gets used both in combination with functions and sets, i.e. $\min f(x)$ is equal to the smallest value the function $f$ attains, and $\min V$, where $V$ some set, is equal to the element of $V$ with the smallest value among all elements.

Does the same hold for $\arg \min$? Obviously, $\arg \min f(x)$ is equal to the $x$-value(s) which correspond(s) with the minimum of the function $f$. More importantly, consider the following:

$$\textbf{x}_{\textrm{LN}} = \textrm{arg min}_{\textbf{x}}\{ \|\textbf{x}\|^2_{2} \ | \ \textbf{x} \in X \}$$

where $X$ some set. In my case,

$$X=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \ | \ A\textbf{x}=\textbf{b}\}$$

Does by the above notation $\textbf{x}_{\textrm{LN}}$ equate to the vector $\textbf{x}$ with the smallest (squared) Euclidean norm which lies in the set X? That is what I would like it to be. If not, what notation would be correct?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Anil

Comment: That is the **least-norm** solution of an underdetermined linear system. The notation looks fine to me.

Comment: Agreed, this notation is fine.  For example, people working in optimal control theory use this notation as you describe, so it is well-established.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I was working on a report which involved the least squares method, so indeed in this case I was referring to the least-norm solution of an underdetermined system. I was unable to find instances where the 'arg min' operator gets used in combination with a set, so that's why I wasn't completely sure about the above notation. Thank you again!